# SQL Statement coming up with errors

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've created a sql statement that works on mysql 5.6.26 but it doesn't work on mysql 5.7.18-0

```
SELECT AVG(total) as mySum , `id` 
FROM (SELECT total,id 
       FROM `figure` 
       where `userid`=156 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4
     ) t1
```

Error that I'm getting:

> Error Static analysis:
>
> 3 errors were found during analysis.
>
> An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 39) Unexpected
>   token. (near "(" at position 39) This type of clause was previously
>   parsed. (near "SELECT" at position 40) SQL query: Documentation
>
> SELECT AVG(total) as mySum , `id` FROM (SELECT total,id FROM `figure`
>   where `userid`=156 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4) t1
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'total' in 'field list'

What am I doing wrong?
Database Structure:
      id  userid total 
       1    156    90
       2    156    30
       3    156    30
       4    156    20
       5    156    30
       6    156    20
       7    156    30
       8    156    40

Comment: Is total actually a column in your figure table?

Comment: please share your ddl of table figure

Comment: While it's unrelated to the error you are getting, in MySQL 5.7 and newer, you will need to include the `id` field in a `GROUP BY` clause since it's not being aggregated by a formula in your `SELECT`. Either that or you will have to set your `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` setting to `false` so that it acts the same as earlier versions.

Comment: And that restriction makes sense, because the query as is displays the avarage of the last four records along with one of their IDs arbitrarily chosen. One should specify *which* ID to show, e.g. `MAX(id)`.

Comment: Yes Jacob it is

Comment: What would be the best solution to fix the problem

Comment: How is phpMyAdmin related to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add column `id` to a `GROUP BY` clause like this:

```
SELECT AVG(total) as mySum , `id` 
FROM (SELECT total, id 
      FROM `figure` 
      WHERE `userid`= 156 
      ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 4
     ) t1
GROUP BY `id`
```

Comment: Instead of getting one row which I wanted I am getting four would it be possible to get just one row

Comment: You need to display the `id`? The `GROUP BY` clause will do de average for each `id` you have. If you dont need to display it, you remove the `id` field and the `GROUP BY` clause to show just one value.

Comment: if you really want the `id` you can try like this: `SELECT AVG(total) as mySum , GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ' ') ids
FROM (SELECT total, id 
      FROM figure 
      WHERE userid= 156 
      ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4
     ) t1`